# rotate kafka 0.8 logs in a linux server

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

in the process of rotating kafka logs(kafka 0.8.1.1), I've managed to rotate all of them, except kafkaServer.out.
this is not handled by log4j.
after looking in kafka-run-class.sh which is the script that starts the java process, it runs with redirection to a file.
i cannot rotate the file unless kafka is restarted.
truncating it, the process just ignores it and keeps on writing to the file.

is there a way to force it to rotate this log file ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a C++ tool called 'rotate' to solve the problem. Source code can be found here, https://github.com/peihanw/rotate

After compile and deploy to $APP_HOME/bin/rotate, please modify the start command in kafka-run-class.sh, here is my example:

```
nohup $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@" < /dev/null | $APP_HOME/bin/rotate -o "$CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FILE" -t 1 &
```

And some additional dustman like maintenance tools or scripts can be configured to compress or remove expire 'kafkaServer.out.YYYYmmddHHMMSS' files.